# Fit a regression model over sequenced data

Tags: python, pandas, regression, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I'm currently trying to find commute times between stops. I want to use a regression model or neural network to predict times but I'm not sure how to fit the model over the data. My data looks like:

```
Route  Station    Trip_ID  Time   Day_Week
1      Station 1  XXX_1    02:30  0       
1      Station 2  XXX_1    02:40  0
1      Station 3  XXX_1    02:55  0
1      Station 4  XXX_1    02:58  0
1      Station 5  XXX_1    03:10  0
```

I want to be able to input any two sets of stations such as (3, 5) or (1, 4) and get an estimate for the commute time between these two. I have over 40,000 data points and 80 different trip ids with each trip having different combinations of stations within it. I'm wondering how a regression model or any type of predictive model would be able to be fitted over this data.

It's the sequencing portion that is confusing to me. Would the model have to predict the commute times between Station 3 -> Station 4 + Station 4 -> Station 5 to get the Station 3 -> Station 5 commute time?

Comment: If the order is what is bothering you, you could reorganize the data such that every row of your dataframe represents a possible combination of stations. So, in your example above, Station 1 -> Station 2, Station 1 -> Station 3, etc. Then you can include an interaction term between the starting station and ending station to get the estimates for any combinations. Obviously this will blow up the size of your dataset, though. Just be warned that you will need to account for clustering within Trip_ID somehow. And modeling when breaking the inherent order of the system is not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Your model has to predict the commute time between start and end stations. You can calculate time differences between every two stations:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
X = df['Station']
y = df['Time'].diff().dt.seconds.fillna(0).div(60).cumsum()
m, b = np.polyfit(X, y, deg=1)

print(y)
```

Output:

```
1     0.0
1    10.0
1    25.0
1    28.0
1    40.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Then you can fit, for example, a linear function:

```
m, b = np.polyfit(X, y, deg=1)

X_test = np.linspace(1, 5, 1000)
y_test = m * X_test + b

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X_test, y_test)
plt.xlabel('station')
plt.ylabel('min')
```

[image]

To get an estimate for the commute time you need to multiply the slope `m` with the number of stations:

```
def predict_time(st1, st2):
    return (st2 - st1) * m

print(predict_time(2, 5))
# 29.4
```